# Nothing happens with this command and don't know why. Everything looks fine

Tags: python, discord.py

```
class EconomyCog(commands.Cog, name="Help"):

def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

@commands.command()
async def Money(self, ctx, member:discord.Member):
    member = ctx.author
    member_id = ctx.author.id
    db = sqlite3.connect("main.sqlite")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT member_id FROM main WHERE member_id = {member_id}")
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        sql = (f"INSERT INTO main(member_id, money) VALUES(?, ?)")
        val = (member_id, 500)
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
        db.commit
        await ctx.send("Because you didn't have an account, I just made one for you!")
        db.close
        cursor.close
    elif result is not None:
        db = sqlite3.connect("main.sqlite")
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM main WHERE member_id = {member_id}")
        result = cursor.fetchone()

        embed = discord.Embed(title = f"{member}'s Money", description = f"{result[1]} <:BitCoin:929595745500274689>", color = discord.Colour.random)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I don't get any errors but also when the command is triggered nothing happens. You have any clue to why it won't work?

Comment: (1) You aren't calling your functions, parens are missing.  See below.  (2) You should close the cursor before closing the database.  (3) You do not need to recreate `db` and `cursor` in the `elif` clause; you already created them.  (4) Don't say `elif result is not None:`; just say `else:`.

Answer (score 1):

These lines do nothing.  They don't call functions, they just mention the function objects:

```
        db.commit
...
        db.close
        cursor.close
```

It's exactly like writing:

```
        7
```

It is syntactically legal, but does nothing.

To call them, you MUST use parens.  Also note that you don't need to refetch the member record in the else; you can have that first query serve both purposes:

```
async def Money(self, ctx, member:discord.Member):
    member = ctx.author
    member_id = ctx.author.id
    db = sqlite3.connect("main.sqlite")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM main WHERE member_id = ?", (member_id,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        sql = (f"INSERT INTO main(member_id, money) VALUES(?, ?)")
        val = (member_id, 500)
        cursor.execute(sql, val)
        db.commit()
        await ctx.send("Because you didn't have an account, I just made one for you!")
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title = f"{member}'s Money", description = f"{result[1]} <:BitCoin:929595745500274689>", color = discord.Colour.random)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
```

Comment: Hey man, thank you for the comment! After implementing this into the code, nothing seemed to happen when the command was triggered. I checked the database to see if it at least added it there but nothing.

Comment: Are you seeing the response message?  In your "else" clause, I think you want `member.name` instead of `member`.